# any other ways similar to observer pattern

Tags: java, observer-pattern, agents-jade

I was asked to implement the function which waits for some action to be done. Then lets it do whatever it is supposed to do. I was asked not to use observer class. I tried with infinite loop and it worked. So i wonder if there are any other ways i could do that. (im developing an app in Jade where an supper agent communicates with other agents and once a message is received by and agent he can do some function and send back a message). I want something for that waiting part. Thanks in advance

Comment: How about producer-consumer [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem]

Comment: the link you sent doesnt work. but ill do a search on the topic. Thanks for answering.

Comment: During paste of the link, its adding some other chars. Try searching producer-consumer problem in google. it might help you

Comment: It sounds like you need a callback method. Try looking into it http://stackoverflow.com/a/24900377/2413303

Comment: Is it forbidden to use the observer pattern or just the observer class? In the latter case you can create your own Observer/Listener classes/interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an action listener?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

You can wait for the desired action and once triggered, you can implement your function.